# Phonegap WebSQL Transaction on Ajax Success not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, web-sql

On the home page of my app, a list of cities loads via ajax call to php, then json back to the app.  I ran this for a long time and works no problem, but now i am wanting to save the data returned in a database.

I got the below working, works on chrome, safari.  But.. when i package it up with phonegap build and load it to my phone..  It does not.

```
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
  }, false);

  dbName = "database5";
  var database = null;
  function onDeviceReady(){
      database = window.openDatabase(dbName,"1.0", "247 Chiropractor", 5 * 1024 * 1024);
      database.transaction(PopulateDatabase, errorOpenDB, successOpenDB);
  }
```

I have debugged this as far as i can go, well using alerts anyhow, to see where the code fails.

It is failing inside my ajax for loop, my execute sql transaction is where it fails. `tx.executeSql`

```
      function PopulateDatabase(tx){
          tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appCities` (`ac_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,`ac_city1` TEXT, `ac_city2` TEXT, `ac_city3` TEXT, `ac_city4` TEXT, `ac_city5` TEXT, `ac_dateadded` TEXT)', AjaxError, AjaxSuccess);

        function AjaxError(){
            alert("AjaxError!");
        }

        function AjaxSuccess(tx){
            $.ajax({
                url: preURL+"getCities.php",
                //async : false,
                success: function(data){
                        var date = new Date();
                        var date = +date;
                        var timestamp = new Date(date);
                        for(i = 0;i < data.length; i++){
                            tx.executeSql("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO appCities VALUES("+data[i].ac_id+",'"+data[i].city1+"','','','','','"+timestamp+"')");
                        }

                        afterAjax();
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    $('#msgToUser').html('<br><h2 align="center">. .oops!. .</h2><p style="padding:10px">There was an error. It is possible that you may not have signal. Please connect to wifi or make sure you have cellular signal and restart this application. If you believe you recieved this error by mistake, please contact us</p>');
                }
            });
        }
      }
```

I have tried async false, but that causes my ajax call to fail and the error function is triggered.

I have spent probly around 10 hours of the past 2 days trying to get this working, i would appreciate any help.

- Is there a plugin i need for websql to work on iOS Phonegap?

Comment: There is a plugin I have seen recommended. I have not used it. Here is the [registry link](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.triarc.sqliteplugin). BTW, what are you trying to do with the date stuff? `timestamp = Date.now()` would give you the millis, or just `timestamp = new Date()` would be the same as your current code, unless I am missing something. Last comment: the actual error would be helpful if you have it.

Comment: Hi Barry, I use date in that fashion because it returns this "Sat Mar 21 2015 18:51:09 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)" instead of mill.  I was using this more for testing.  Also, I do not have an actual error.  I even added a callback to my transaction inside the loop and nothing happens.  Again this works on chrome/safari, not ios iphone with phonegap.  Thank you for the link, i will check this out and return the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a WebSQL in my Phonegap/Cordova apps on iOS/Android. I use operation chaining via callbacks to perform sequential operations and this seems to work fine on both platforms. Applying this principle to your code, I would do something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}, false);

dbName = "database5";
var database = null;
var ajaxData = null;

function onDeviceReady(){
  database = window.openDatabase(dbName,"1.0", "247 Chiropractor", 5 * 1024 * 1024);
  doAjax();
}

function doAjax(){
    $.ajax({
         url: preURL+"getCities.php",
         //async : false,
         success: AjaxSuccess,
         error: function(data) {
             $('#msgToUser').html('<br><h2 align="center">. .oops!. .</h2><p style="padding:10px">There was an error. It is possible that you may not have signal. Please connect to wifi or make sure you have cellular signal and restart this application. If you believe you recieved this error by mistake, please contact us</p>');
         }
    });
}

function AjaxSuccess(data){
     ajaxData = data;
     database.transaction(CreateDatabase, errorOpenDB, successOpenDB);
}

function SqlError(){
     alert("SqlError!");
}

function CreateDatabase(tx){
     tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appCities` (`ac_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,`ac_city1` TEXT, `ac_city2` TEXT, `ac_city3` TEXT, `ac_city4` TEXT, `ac_city5` TEXT, `ac_dateadded` TEXT)', SqlError, CreateSuccess);
}

function CreateSuccess(tx){
     var date = new Date();
     var date = +date;
     var timestamp = new Date(date);
     doInserts(timestamp, tx);
}

function doInserts(timestamp, tx){
    if(ajaxData.length > 0{
        var data = ajaxData.shift();
        tx.executeSql("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO appCities VALUES("+data.ac_id+",'"+data.city1+"','','','','','"+timestamp+"')", SqlError, doInserts.bind(this, timestamp));

    }else{
        insertSuccess();
    }
}

function insertSuccess(){
    console.log("Insert successful");
    afterAjax();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This looks great and your reasoning behind is makes a lot of sense.  and it worked!  I am so happy.  Thank you very much.  I had to do a few small tweaks but your code is fantastic.  I really appreciate you taking the time to customize this for me.  I am new to websql and its a tad foreign to me.  I will be able to implement this on my other apps as well.  goodbye localstorage!  thanks again